# My URLs in the subdomain won't point to the main domain

Tags: html, wordpress, web, cpanel

Starting with an apology if this sounds stupid, but I'm new to this stuff and would really like some help.

I have just created a subdomain, careers.h-dot.com, for my main site. However, the menu bar on my subdomain with all the links to home and other pages does not take the visitor to the main page. Instead, the home page opens in the subdomain e.g. careers.h-dot.com/home instead of h-dot.com/home

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the `href` of the `a` tag with a link to your main site, not your subdomain.

For example

```
<a href="http://h-dot.com/home">Home</a>
```

This **won't work**

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
```